# Specific use of enums in multiple class setting

Tags: c#, enums

Edit: Forgive the unclear title. I wasn't sure exactly how to phrase what I was looking for...

Ok. So. I'm gonna throw a bit of code down here. I know I'm close on this, but the specifics of it are beginning to frustrate me.

Basically, in a class called Actor I have, among other things, set up my Enums thusly:

```
public enum Directions
    {
        Left,
        Up,
        Right,
        Down,
    };
```

Afterwards, I have a switch statement set up to use the Enums, in this way:

```
public void Move(Directions dir)
    {

        switch (dir)
        {
            case Directions.Down:
                _YPosition = _YPosition - 1;
                    break;
            case Directions.Up:
                _YPosition = _YPosition + 1;
                    break;
            case Directions.Left:
                _XPosition = _XPosition - 1;
                    break;
            case Directions.Right:
                _XPosition = _XPosition + 1;
                    break;
        }
```

Now, in the Main class I have 4 buttons that correspond to these enum names. One of them looks like this:

```
private void btnMoveUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        newCharacter.Move();
    }
```

As you have probably realized, I'm getting a "no argument given corresponds to required formal parameters of 'dir'" error in my code.

I've tried putting in the number value for the Enum that corresponds to that button (in the case of Up that's 2) but I get a conversion error.

C# keeps telling me to create a method Actor.Move, which has obviously already been created. There's something simple I'm missing here, and a point in the right direction would be delightful.

Thoughts? Hints?

Comment: yes, `Move` is defined but you are not calling it properly. it expects an argument of type `Directions` which is what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a function `public void Move(Directions dir)`, which takes one parameter named `dir`. You then attempt, it appears, to call that function without passing any parameters: `newCharacter.Move();`

Try passing a parameter. In this case since the outer function is called `btnMoveUp_Click`, you probably want to write `newCharacter.Move(Directions.Up);`

Comment: Thanks! I was just leaving a part of that out, I guess. Your help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the enum properly when calling the function:

```
private void btnMoveUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newCharacter.Move(Directions.Up);
}
```